# Ionic 6 increment decrement button not working

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm making my first Ionic App (Ionic 6) and Angular. The app is a shop. I'm trying to make a number input field with + and - buttons to increase quantity. The problem I'm facing is that my + and - buttons don't work. If I use the arrows that appear near the number (I think they are default html browser up and down arrows from every number input field) the number increases and the final price calculation works. But clicking on my + and - buttons does nothing... no error in compiler and no error in browser console..

Here is the image of layout and my code:
[image]

***subcategory.page.html:***

```
          <ion-list>
        <ion-item class="list-product" *ngFor="let produkt of produktiData;let i = index">
          <ion-grid>
            <ion-row>
              <ion-col size="12">
                <ion-label>
                  <div class="title-price-wrapper">
                    <h2>{{ (produkt.name | slice:0:15) + '...' }}</h2>
                    <p>{{ produkt.price }} <span class="price-per-em">€/{{produkt.enotaMere}}</span></p>
                  </div>
                </ion-label>
              </ion-col>
            </ion-row>
            <ion-row>
              <ion-col size="3">
                <ion-avatar slot="start">
                  <img src="/assets/images/spinach.png"  alt="{{produkt.id}} {{produkt.name}}"/>
                </ion-avatar>
              </ion-col>
              <ion-col size="9">
                <ion-label>
                  <div class="d-flex ion-justify-content-between">
                    <div class="prod-details-wrapper">
                      <p class="product-id">{{ produkt.id }}</p>
                      <p class="product-em">EM: {{ produkt.enotaMere }}</p>
                      <p class="product-packaging">Pakiranje: {{ produkt.grammage }} {{produkt.enotaMere}}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="qty-input-wrapper">
                      <ion-item lines="none" slot="end">
                        <ion-icon name="add-circle" (click)="incrementQty(i)"></ion-icon>
                        <ion-input type="number" min="0" [(ngModel)]="produkt.qty"></ion-input>
                        <ion-icon name="remove-circle" (click)="decrementQty(i)"></ion-icon>
                      </ion-item>
                    </div>
                    <div class="price-calculations-wrapper">
                      <p><strong>{{produkt.qty*produkt.price}}€</strong></p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </ion-label>
              </ion-col>
            </ion-row>
          </ion-grid>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
```

Here is the ***subcategory.page.ts*** code:

```
    export class SubcategoryPage implements OnInit {
  produkti: any = {
    data: [
      {
        id: 460251,
        name: 'Špinača list briketi ZM',
        enotaMere: 'kg',
        grammage: 2.5,
        unitsPerEM: 10,
        unitsPerCarton: 4,
        price: 1.25,
        qty: 1,
        stock: 100,
        description: 'Lorem ipsum product description...',
      },
    ],
  };
  produktiData = this.produkti.data;

  constructor() {
    this.produkti = this.produktiData.map(produkti => {
      produkti.qty = 0;
      return produkti;
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  incrementQty(index: number) {
    this.produkti[index].qty += 1;
  }

  decrementQty(index: number) {
    this.produkti[index].qty -= 1;
  }

}
```

What have I done wrong? wheree is the problem that the buttons don't work? Please help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your buttons refer to `produkti`array, while you loop `produktiData` array in your template. Try to loop `produkti`in your template instead.

`<ion-item class="list-product" *ngFor="let produkt of produkti;let i = index">`